# Does snmp_exporter support AES 256 if does then what will be the snmp.yml file structure

Tags: aes, prometheus, snmp, exporter

SNMP_Exporter works fine when snmp.yml file when

```
default:
  version: 3
  auth:
    username: SomeUser
    password: TotallySecret
    auth_protocol: SHA
    priv_protocol: AES
    security_level: SomethingReadOnly
    priv_password: SomeOtherSecret
  walk:
    - ...
  metrics:
    - ...
```

AES by default here means with 128 bit key i think
so what changes would i have to make to walk a device that is using AES 256 bit key as privacy protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES256 is not a part of the SNMP standard, though some vendors have custom support for it. If you want it added to the SNMP exporter you will first need to get it added our upstream at https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/